# C# pattern to pass what amounts to a subclass?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, design-patterns

Given a virtually simulated tablet which launches apps like FooApp and BarApp which inherit from class App, what would be a good way to tell a function LaunchApp(...) which app to launch?

I'm currently passing LaunchApp(System.Type appType), where appType is e.g. typeof(FooApp), which then gets validated within the function. However, this pattern seems to lack proper type safety and passing autocompletion comfort. An alternative pattern on the other hand, where I use an Enum which then gets converted to the appType via e.g. switch-case, doesn't seem to adhere to D.R.Y. as I need to keep another redundant appType enum list. What would be a good pattern here?

Comment: `LaunchApp<T>() where T : App`? Not knowing what `LaunchApp` needs to do, it's quite hard to give more ideas. If you could provide concrete example code, that would really help.

Comment: Basically LaunchApp(x) always does the same -- it closes an existing app, then adds the specific FooApp (which is always expected to be a subclass of App) to a new Unity GameObject via AddComponent(x). The only difference is the specific app subclass, which I can currently agnostically just pass on in 1 line of code, which is nice (and preferable to any long switch-case): void OpenApp(System.Type appType) { currentApp = (App) appObject.AddComponent(appType); }

Comment: Please edit that into the question. (It sounds like it's quite possibly fine to use a generic method, but I'm not entirely sure...)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you wish for a different method to be called depending on the type of your object. But don't want to introduce a new enum to help make the decision of which method to call.

For this, i suggest you can use the type pattern working in newer C# versions. Where it casts your objects type and runs the switch case for that particular type.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch

Here is the example they use in the documentation.

```
private static void ShowCollectionInformation(object coll)
    {
        switch (coll)
        {
            case Array arr:
               Console.WriteLine($"An array with {arr.Length} elements.");
               break;
            case IEnumerable<int> ieInt:
               Console.WriteLine($"Average: {ieInt.Average(s => s)}");
               break;   
            case IList list:
               Console.WriteLine($"{list.Count} items");
               break;
            case IEnumerable ie:
               string result = "";
               foreach (var e in ie) 
                  result += "${e} ";
               Console.WriteLine(result);
               break;   
            case null:
               // Do nothing for a null.
               break;
            default:
               Console.WriteLine($"A instance of type {coll.GetType().Name}");
               break;   
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I believe it might be more of a case of calling a specific, always-same-approach method that simply adds the subclass as component. Maybe my use-case is too obscure...

Comment: Well it can work for that too. Although you would of course need to make a case for each type, which wouldnt be as generic as you seek. Alternatively   perhaps you can use GetType to get it somehow, or a method with <T> or something of the sort. Personally id probably go with the switch casting and then make a manager method that receives the desired parameters and relevant GameObject. That would mean only adding types one place. But lets see if someone else has a more generic solution.

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/unityscript-api-change-addcomponent-with-custom-type.280035/

Comment: Based on the above link example. TypeOf should work for the purpose. If i understand correctly what you wish to do.

Comment: Thank you. TypeOf is what I'm currently using, though I was curious if there was a pattern that makes passing of System.Type safer, as it allows any type and can't be autocompleted, while not managing a redundant big Enum or Switch-Case. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You can lock the type passed into a method to have to be a subtype of an interface or class.

public void YourMethod<T>(T t) where T : IYourType
{
//Do stuff
}

Comment: Oh! That sounds like it then!